# Setting Content from Code-Behind using Resources

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, xaml-resources

I am currently designing a UI for an UWP application. I have a Splitview set up that has a content I want to set from the code-behind depending on user interaction.

In the Resources, I have some Menus set up that I can set without a single problem from the content property itself:

```
<SplitView x:Name="NavPane" OpenPaneLength="250" CompactPaneLength="50" Content="{StaticResource Home}" DisplayMode="CompactOverlay" IsPaneOpen="False" PaneClosing="NavPane_PaneClosing">
```

What I would like to do now is use the content property to bind to a FrameworkElement variable in the Code-behind.

How can I do this while, if possible, keeping my menus set up in xaml? Or is there a method others use that i just haven't caught on to yet?

Any help is appreciated very much.

Comment: Could you post more codes or a demo project to show how you bind the menus to your splitview?

Answer (score 0):

I watched the UWP series tutorial of Microsoft and I learned that there are different ways to Data Bind. To be more accurate, [you may check this link of Microsoft showing you different examples.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-quickstart)
I hope it helps!

Comment: The problem isn't the binding itself, but rather how to access the elements in some way from the code-behind. I have tried different methods, but they all seem to create some error.